# Alterar atributos de classe a partir de método genérico

Tags: python-3.x

Tenho uma classe com muitos atributos e gostaria de poder alterar esses atributos a partir de um método genérico onde deve-se passar o nome do atributo a ser alterado e o novo valor.

```
class Classe_com_muitos_atributos:
   def __init__(self, atr1, atr2, atr4 ...):
      self.atr1 = 5
      self.atr2 = 5
      self.atr3 = 5
      self.atr4 = 5
      #muitos atributos...

   def altera_atributo(self, var_com_o_nome_do_atributo, valor):
      self.var_com_nome_do_atributo = valor
```

A idéia é que o método seja executado da seguinte forma:

```
instancia.altera_atributo('atr2', 10)
```

Minha dificuldade é que o python procura na classe, um atributo com o nome "var_com_o_nome_do_atributo" e não sei como fazer para que, ao invés disso, ele procure na classe pelo atributo que está contido na variável, neste exemplo, atr2.

Imagino que deve ser algo simples, mas estou começando agora e não estou encontrando a solução.

Comment: Então pra que fazer uma classe? Não seria melhor fazer um dicionário?

Comment: muitos dos "atributos" da classe são dicionários... o método é justamente pra facilitar o acesso

Comment: Digo para usar dicionário no lugar da classe, se quer algo de acesso dinâmico você não quer uma classe. É até possível fazer o que deseja, mas pra que? Use a ferramenta certa para a tarefa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O comentário do Maniero me ajudou na resolução. A classe continua sendo uma classe mas os atributos semelhantes foram transformados em um único dicionário (como atributo da classe). Não sei se é uma boa prática mas resolveu.

Comment: Inicialmente usar um dicionario como uma classe resolveu, mas como parecia muito um POG, fui estudar POO (em c# que tô mais acostumado), me pareceu uma solução mais elegante utilizar uma subclasse como atributo uma vez que só os valores mudam, os índices são imutáveis e utilizados em muitos lugares.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o [setattr](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/setattr). 
Sua função altera_atributo vai ficar assim:

```
def altera_atributo(self, var_com_o_nome_do_atributo, valor):
  setattr(self, var_com_o_nome_do_atributo, valor)
```